# How do I change a monitor's physical dimensions in the Windows 10 Display settings for Multiple Monitor settings?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

In the Display settings in Windows 10, I am trying to set up multiple monitors (a 15" and a 23"), but Windows believes they are the same physical dimensions, so when I set them for Extended Desktop, the cursor jumps around when moving between displays.

There is no way to arrange these screens to fix this problem, because Windows does not understand they are different sizes. Can this be adjusted somewhere?

[image: Multiple Monitor arrange displays]

Comment: You can drag the monitor to be offset, however, the size is based on the resolution.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

It also wouldn’t matter, because neither physical dimensions nor the scaling factor affect how the cursor (or anything else) transitions between screens. It’s purely pixel-based.

Consider the following example:

[image]

The left display (1) is a 15″ 4K laptop display. The right display (2) is a 27″ 2560x1440 display. The left display (1) is set to 200% scaling, making the “effective” resolution 1920x1080. None of it matters, except the real resolution.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool that I found pretty useful:
https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse

1. Just Download from the release page: https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse/releases
2. Run it and configure:
   [image: Screenshot of LittleBigMouse]

   - Make sure to check the `Load at Startup`-Option.
   - You can configure the Screensize and Location on the top.
   - To move your mouse automatically and keep it from getting stuck at the edges select the `Allow Corner Crossing`.

Comment: Link only answer is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Comment: Sure, but if the link does not work my answer is useless anyway, as it will be specific to the tool.

Answer (score -2):

I think if you go to settings and go to System/Display/Advanced Display Settings/ you can select the monitors separately and change the settings there

Comment: There are no physical dimensions listed on that screen at all. the only thing editable there is Refresh Rate. I'm not sure if Microsoft has ever allowed the dimensions to be edited anywhere. Every time I've had monitors of different sizes, it just seemed to guess their relative sizes. In most cases, it was close. In this case, it's showing them the same size, but they aren't.